# Argument of type '(event: string) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript

I have added an event listener to my div.

```
componentWillMount() {
    document.addEventListener('keyPress', this.handleKey, false)
  }

componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('keyPress', this.handleKey, false)
  }
```

Here is my function:

```
handleKey = (event: string) => {
   console.log(event)
  }

render(){
  return(
      <div className={classes.scAccountDropDown} onKeyDown={(event: any) => this.handleKey(event.key)}>
)
```

But after compiling I'm getting  "Argument of type '(event: string) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject."

Comment: You have `event: string` but you assign it as a listener so you'd be receiving an `Event` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that inside `render` you are passing `string` as a parameter to `handleKey` function:

```
onKeyDown={(event: any) => this.handleKey(event.key)}
```

But, both in `componentWillMount` and `componentWillUnmount` you are passing the actual `KeyboardEvent` event to the `handleKey` function, which is causing this issue. You can fix this by updating them like:

```
componentWillMount() {
  document.addEventListener('keyPress', (e: any) => this.handleKey(e.key), false)
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  document.removeEventListener('keyPress', (e: any) => this.handleKey(e.key), false)
}
```

You can also update `handleKey()` function to make it clear that you are getting `key` as a param to this function, not the actual event.

```
handleKey = (key: string) => {
   console.log(key)
}
```